# SOLR "LIKE" query syntax for non-string data type

Tags: php, solr, wildcard

I've a problem with my query SOLR syntax. On admin page, I've tried to use this query

```
description:*home*
```

and the result is all doc that contain "home" word in the description field.

but, when I try to do something like that for price field (which has a data type float), there is no result for it.

Can anybody tell me how to use the wildcard syntax in SOLR for number data types (like integer, float, real, etc.) ?

thanks_

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do wildcard searches against numbers.  But if you need to maybe you could store the numbers in a text field and run your wildcard queries against that.

Probably what you actually want to do is a range query on your number fields.  Something like:

```
price:[17 TO *]   ' 17 or higher
price:[17 TO 18]  ' between 17 and 18 (inclusive)
```

See [SolrQuerySyntax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax)

If this doesn't help, maybe let us know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm making a search function now. If I input something in a text field (e.g 45000), then I use SOLR to get all field that contain the input, no matter the data type is string or number.
I wish you could help me,thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here.  Please be clear on what you're trying to accomplish and what you've tried and I will try to help

Comment: I've a text field that will be used by the user to enter keywords and search button to do search action. In my docs, for example I have 3 fields, price (float), name (string) and description (string). When user enter the keywords and then click search button to do the action, it will search all field of docs that contain these keywords. So, I use wildcard to do this. It's works for string data type, but not on float data type. In my search action, I use loop to search in every field on each docs. I hope you can understand what I mean,.

Comment: Why do you need to use wildcards?  Note that if you're using the dismax query parser, searching for description:*home* is the exact same as description:home  This is because the *'s are stripped out, dismax does not support wildcards.  Look in your solrconfig.xml file for <str name="defType">dismax</str>.

Answer (score 0):

try description:* home * (with spaces between the '*' and value)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).